# Jquery listeners and conditions. Reversed results?

Tags: jquery, listener, conditional-statements

I'm not sure what's wrong with these listeners. Its suppose to be "choose from first row boxes (like 49) and then from second rows boxes Like 52)" and its suppose to show or hide divs.

Instead it works if you select one of the second rows boxes (like 52) than choosing any of the first row boxes (like 49)

I'm definitely missing something. I'm not sure what.

Here is the [Jfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/epudL/29/)

```
    function showByArray(name, idArray){
    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++){
        jQuery('#'+name+'-'+idArray[i]).show();
    }
}

function hideByArray(name, idArray){
    for(var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++){
        jQuery('#'+name+'-'+idArray[i]).hide();
    }
}

function namechecker(id,otherId, name, idArray){
            if (jQuery('#'+id).is(':checked') && jQuery('#'+otherId).is(':checked')) 
            {
                showByArray(name,idArray);                                  
                return;
            }else{
                hideByArray(name,idArray);
            }
}

    function namecheckerquad(id,otherId, otherIds, name, idArray){
                if (jQuery('#'+id).is(':checked') ||  jQuery('#'+otherId).is(':checked') ||  jQuery('#'+otherIds).is(':checked')) 
                {
                    showByArray(name,idArray);                                  
                    return;
                }else{
                    hideByArray(name,idArray);
                }
    }


$('#in-name-49').click(function(){
namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315]);
namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-311', 'name', [306,307, 308]);
});    


$('#in-name-50').click(function(){
namechecker('in-name-50', 'in-name-52', 'name', [316,317]);
namechecker('in-name-50', 'in-name-311', 'name', [309,310]);
});

$('#in-name-279').click(function(){
namechecker('in-name-279', 'in-name-52', 'name',[313,314, 315,316,317]);
namechecker('in-name-279', 'in-name-311', 'name',[306,307, 308,309,310]);
});

$('#in-name-242').click(function(){
namechecker('in-name-242', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317] );
namechecker('in-name-242', 'in-name-311', 'name',[306,307, 308,309,310]);
});

$('#in-name-52').click(function(){
namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315]);
namechecker('in-name-50', 'in-name-52', 'name', [316,317]);
namechecker('in-name-279', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317]);
namechecker('in-name-242', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317]);
});

$('#in-name-311').click(function(){
namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-311', 'name', [306,307, 308]);
namechecker('in-name-50', 'in-name-311', 'name', [309,310]);
namechecker('in-name-279', 'in-name-311', 'name', [306,307, 308,309,310]);
namechecker('in-name-242', 'in-name-311', 'name', [306,307, 308,309,310]);
});
```

Comment: The JSFiddle helped a lot. I updated my answer to include a working version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary

What's happening here is that when your listeners fire, you're running `namechecker` multiple times, which will show or hide the elements depending on the order of the `namechecker` calls inside of the listener. You want to not do that.

I'll explain how this is happening by example, provide two ways for you to verify this yourself, and finally provide you a working solution.

### Example

For example: say you click the 49 checkbox, invoking this listener:

```
$('#in-name-49').click(function(){
    namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315]);  //runs once for 52
    namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-311', 'name', [306,307, 308]); //runs once for 311
});
```

Then you run `namechecker` twice (once for 52 and once for 311) hiding the elements 313, 314, and 315 because 52 isn't checked, and then hiding 306, 307, and 308 because or 311 isn't checked. That's fine, that's the expected result.

Now, if you click on the 52 checkbox then you will run `namechecker` four times:

```
$('#in-name-52').click(function(){
    namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315]);          //will show the elements
    namechecker('in-name-50', 'in-name-52', 'name', [316,317]);               //will hide the elements
    namechecker('in-name-279', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317]); //will hide the elements
    namechecker('in-name-242', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317]); //will hide the elements
});
```

Since the 49 box is checked, when `namechecker` runs the first time, it will show elements 313, 314, and 315. But then `namechecker` runs *again*, and since 50 is **not** checked, it will hide elements. Same for the next two times it runs, and the last time it runs it hides 313,314, 315--which are the elements you showed in the first call!

Thus, you *are* showing the elements, but then you're immediately, inadvertently, hiding them again.

### Verify

#### Method 1

You can verify this by checking 242 and then checking 52. Since the last time `namechecker` runs inside the listener for 52 is for 242, the last thing it will do in the lister for 52 is show the elements [313,314, 315,316,317].

#### Method 2

You can also verify this by moving around the order of the `namechecker` calls in the listener of 52 to get the items to appear after a 49-then-52 sequence ([see this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epudL/32/)):

```
$('#in-name-52').click(function(){
    namechecker('in-name-50', 'in-name-52', 'name', [316,317]);
    namechecker('in-name-279', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317]);
    namechecker('in-name-242', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315,316,317]);
    namechecker('in-name-49', 'in-name-52', 'name', [313,314, 315]); //moved to the end
});
```

## Solution

The better way to do this is to register one function to all of the listeners, and every time that function runs it will hide all of the elements and then go over all of your `namechecker` functions at once to show the ones that are supposed to be visible.

[Here's is a working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/epudL/34/)

Comment: Well Rick, Hats off. Thank you , this made it so much more clearer. 

How ever i'm wondering whether adding "hidable" class would replace the current class that's given to the divs. Though ive not included this to my codes, the original codes were generated through Wordpress and have already classes on their own. 

thank you alot.